# The 'gap' command is missing in wordpress css. How do I add it?

Tags: css, wordpress

Trying to edit the theme's style.css. I type in gap:

```
gap: 0;
```

but the `gap` command shows up red in the console which I assume that means `gap` is not a valid command. `column-gap` works but `row-gap` doesn't either.

Comment: CSS matters to the browser so you can ignore the red underline.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.